# Haskell: bound-values in generic functions

Tags: haskell

i want to do something like:

```
succ' :: (Bounded a, Eq a, Enum a) => a -> a
succ' n
| n == (maxBound :: a) = minBound :: a
| otherwise = succ n
```

but this does not work. how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the type annotations, and they're the source of the errors you're getting:

```
succ' :: (Bounded a, Eq a, Enum a) => a -> a
succ' n
 | n == maxBound = minBound
 | otherwise = succ n
```

(This works in Haskell 98 and Haskell 2010, so pretty much any compiler you've got lying around .)
Also, I indented the `|` a little, because they can't line up with the start of the function; they're part of the definition of `succ'`, not standalone code.

Here's some test data:

```
data Test = A | B | C 
   deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Show)

test = map succ' [A .. C]
```

I got `[B,C,A]`.

Answer (score 7):

Several possibilities, the Haskell2010 way,

```
succ' :: (Bounded a, Eq a, Enum a) => a -> a
succ' n
  | n == maxBound = minBound
  | otherwise = succ n
```

the types are determined from the use, the type of both, `maxBound` and `minBound` must be the type of the argument.

Or you can use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, bring the type variable into scope so it can be used in local type signatures,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

succ' :: forall a. (Bounded a, Eq a, Enum a) => a -> a
succ' n
  | n == (maxBound :: a) = minBound :: a
  | otherwise = succ n
```

but, as seen above, there's no need for that here.

A third possibility is to use `asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`,

```
succ' :: (Bounded a, Eq a, Enum a) => a -> a
succ' n
  | n == (maxBound `asTypeOf` n) = minBound `asTypeOf` n
  | otherwise                    = succ n
```

which, again, is not needed here, but can be useful in other situations.