# Cycling a value (Enum a, Bounded a) => a

Tags: haskell, enums

I'm looking for the pair of functions

```
previous :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
next     :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
```

Such that `previous` is `pred :: Enum a => a -> a` if the resulting value will be constrained by the bounds, and cycle it to the other side otherwise (symmetrical for `next` and `succ`).

Example

```
data X = A | B | C deriving (Bounded, Enum)
next A = B
next B = C
next C = A
```

This would be easy if I were to add the `Eq a => a` constraint, as discussed in these [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788202/is-there-a-way-to-plus-one-to-an-enum-bounded-ord-type-in-a-list-in-haskell) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387881/haskell-bound-values-in-generic-functions).
But this constraint seems unnecessary, as a `Bounded a => a` type to me sounds like it should be able to tell if its within bound or not. The `succ` and `pred` functions themselves have some kind of control over this, but I would rather not use Exceptions in my otherwise pure code:

```
Prelude> succ (maxBound :: Int)
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.succ{Int}: tried to take `succ' of maxBound
```

How does `succ`/`pred` test against the bounds without requiring `Eq a => a` (or even `Bounded a => a`)? Can I replicate this behavior in my own function? Or is there another way to write a function with this behavior and not requiring the `Eq` constraint?

Comment: `succ` is given by some implementation that can determine whether it’s valid or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Enum` class defines two functions

```
  toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a
  fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int
```

These functions can be used to compare an `Enum` to another, if the range of that `Enum` fits into the size of `Int`. If you are willing to accept this slight limitation, you can write your functions as follows.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

previous :: forall a . (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
previous x | from x > from minBound = pred x 
           | otherwise              = maxBound where from :: a -> Int; from = fromEnum 

next :: forall a . (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
next x | from x < from maxBound = succ x 
       | otherwise              = minBound where from :: a -> Int; from = fromEnum
```

These functions make several assumptions; that given `(Enum a, Bounded a)`, every value of `a` will be between the `minBound` and `maxBound`, inclusive, and that `{to/from}Enum` preserve this ordering, with respect to the ordering on integers. This is true for simple enumerations:

```
>import Control.Arrow
>map (next &&& previous) [A,B,C]
[(B,C),(C,A),(A,B)]
```

Comment: This looks great! Are these limitations always caught by the type system? Trying it out on GHCi, `previous 10` gives a compilation-time error while `previous (10 :: Int)` works fine.

Comment: No they are not. If an instance of `Enum` has more elements than the size of `Int`, then `from/toEnum` simply break. `succ` and `pred` may still work.

Comment: `previous 10` is a valid expression whose type would be `Num a, Enum a, Bounded a => a`, however, GHCI can't print it because it doesn't know which type to pick for `a`. Usually it picks `Integer` but that isn't `Bounded`. If you type `default (Int)` into your GHCI session, then it will try defaulting to `Int` instead - so `previous 10` will be defaulted to `Int`, and will work without a type signature.

Answer (score 5):

What's the problem? If you can add the `Eq` class too, it's easy:

```
module CycleEnum where

data XEnum = A1 | A2 | A3 deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Show)

cyclePrev :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cyclePrev x = if x == minBound then maxBound else pred x

cycleNext :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cycleNext x = if x == maxBound then minBound else succ x
```

Without `Eq`, it's slightly more complicated...

```
module CycleEnum where

data XEnum = A1 | A2 | A3 deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)

isSingle :: [a] -> Bool
isSingle [x] = True
isSingle _ = False

isLastElement :: Enum a => a -> Bool
isLastElement x = isSingle $ enumFrom x

isFirstElement :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> Bool
isFirstElement x = isSingle $ enumFromTo minBound x

cyclePrev :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cyclePrev x = if isFirstElement x then maxBound else pred x

cycleNext :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cycleNext x = if isLastElement x then minBound else succ x
```

Note that I wrote `isSingle` with pattern matching, and not by calling `length`; because calculating the length of a list can be very inefficient if you just want to know if the list contains exactly one element.

Comment: This solution has apparently the same limitations as user2407038's answer (`cycleNext 10` gives compilation-time error, `cyclenext (10 :: Int)` works fine), but does not require `-XScopedTypeVariables`. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, for some of the typeclass instances, it simply defines the functions as you have done with your example:

```
instance Enum Ordering where
  succ LT = EQ
  succ EQ = GT
  succ GT = error "Prelude.Enum.Ordering.succ: bad argument"

  pred GT = EQ
  pred EQ = LT
  pred LT = error "Prelude.Enum.Ordering.pred: bad argument"
```

Otherwise, as you say, it seems most likely that you're going to need to allow for `Eq`, because fundamentally there must be some concept of comparison (in order to compare the bounds against the current value), if the full space of the type can't be easily enumerated.

Comment: And how can `succ` do this without `(Bounded a, Eq a) => a`? Is it a "primitives can break rules" case?

Comment: I think it's simply that `succ` does not require any bounds or equality testing; it requires only that there be a function `a -> a`. Quite literally, it could (uselessly) be the same thing as the `id` function.

Comment: @Mephy: In the `Enum` instance for a given type, `succ` is defined specifically for _that one type_, not generally, and can exploit _anything_ about that one type.  For example, here `succ` is being defined for `Ordering`.  Any function on `Ordering` is fair game.  `succ` can be _used_ generally, but it's _implemented_ once per type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman an oversight on my part, thanks for your explanation.